# How to .format expressions like f string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, f-string

Consider the following program:

```
$ python -c 'import sys; print(sys.argv[1].format(**dict(val = 1)))' "val={val}"
val=1
```

However, the f-string functionality is not available in .format:

```
$ python -c 'import sys; print(sys.argv[1].format(**dict(val = 1)))' "val={'1' if val else '2'}"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: "'1' if val else '2'"
```

How can I use f-string formatting capabilities with format string and a dictionary both set at runtime?

I tried the following, however I do not know how to "trigger" f-string evaluation on a string:

```
python -c 'import sys; locals().update(dict(val=1)); print(sys.argv[1])' "val={'1' if val else '2'}"
```

I could do this and it works:

```
$ python -c 'import sys; locals().update(dict(val=1)); print(eval(f"f{sys.argv[1]!r}"))' "val={'1' if val else '2'}"
val=1
```

However, it feels way like a hack. Is there a better way?

Comment: If you want to execute a string containing Python code, there's really no way around selling you soul to using `eval` or the like. But beware the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/478746). If you add some more details about your intended use case, someone may be able to suggest a different approach that better meets your needs

Comment: I don't think this is possible. It also seems like it could be pretty unsafe if it was.

Comment: The XY problem is to give users an easy templating engine to specify output log messages format.

Comment: Maybe something like `defaults = {"val": True}; exec(sys.argv[1], defaults); "...".format(**defaults)` is what you're looking for?

Comment: Then use a *templating engine* like Jinja2 or the like. f-strings are safe and permit this kind of expression because it has to literally appear in source code, not in user-provided values. For anything else where the template is user-provided, you want safe evaluation, for which templating engines exist.